# Skimage RAG merging for gray images

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

Can the skimage RAG support the gray images? For example, in [RAG merging](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_rag_merge.html), it states *This example constructs a Region Adjacency Graph (RAG) and progressively merges regions that are similar in color.*  But can we merge regions in terms of pixel intensity for the gray images?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the RAGs are very flexible. You can see the source code for `rag_mean_color` [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/b2ce774bb5cb7a1f10f1f51c315c18448d7ae891/skimage/future/graph/rag.py#L295). Unfortunately, you can see that 3 channels are assumed in [this line](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/b2ce774bb5cb7a1f10f1f51c315c18448d7ae891/skimage/future/graph/rag.py#L360). It would not be hard to change it to vary according to the number of channels in the input image. In the meantime, though, you can convert a grayscale image to a "color" image (the grayscale repeated three times) by using [`skimage.color.gray2rgb`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.gray2rgb), and then use that example directly.

Note also other RAG examples in the documentation, such as those based on [region boundary values](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_rag_boundary.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-rag-boundary-py).